# Version compatibility of the kafka, Spring Cloud stream and Spring cloud stream binder kafka

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am using `Kafka-client` version of 1.0.0 and `Spring-cloud-stream` version of 2.0.2. now I want to know the version of `Spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` version to stream the events to kafka.

Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    | 
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    | org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: provisioning exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:259) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:149) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:138) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:262) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    | Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:225) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar!/:na]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:288) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:268) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:252) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
headless_api-gateway-service.1.te0u82ql4pkh@node8.docker.com    |   ... 13 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

See the [Spring for Apache Kafka project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) for the compatibility matrix.

Currently

[image]

However, as Oleg said in the deleted answer, a timeout is more likely a mis-configuration (e.g. mismatched SSL). Turn on DEBUG logging to see if it provides more information.

Comment: I guess "Spring for Apache Kafka" refers to "spring-apache-kafka". What artifacts do "Spring Integration for Apache Kafka" refer to?

Comment: spring-kafka and spring-integration-kafka

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#introduction and https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka